# Is there any way to find the status of RabbitMq consumer/listener

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I've written a RabbitMq listener application using spring-boot and want to know the status whether it is processing the messages or idle.

I've been through the rabbitMq HTTP API doc and found   **/api/queues/vhost/name/get** endpoint gives the message count and message body. I see an opportunity in that, decided to compare the message count and message body for two successive responses. If both responses are same then the listener is idle else it's processing.

I used RestTemplate's postForEntity() with {"count":1,"requeue":true,"encoding":"auto"} as request body. But strangely rabbitmq-server isn't responding for this API, however its responding for other API endpoint in the doc.

If there's any way to get the status of the listener, please share the details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask questions like this on the rabbitmq-users google group. The RabbitMQ engineers do not look here often but they actively monitor that group.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AMQP listener containers emit a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` objects when there is no messages during some interval.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#idle-containers

For the RabbitMQ REST API, there is a Java wrapper - `Hop`: https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop

So, consider to use its `Client.getQueue(String vhost, String name)`  for your goal, if a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` doesn't fit your requirements.